# Phonegap 3 - LocalFileSystem not defined

Tags: xcode, cordova

I used this code in phonegap 2.6.0 and it worked, now I upgraded to phonegap 3.0.0 and xcode 5 and I get this error:

```
onDeviceReady: =>
    try
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, failFS)
    catch e
        alert(e)


**ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined**
```

I get the same error in Chrome, and that I guess is normal?

The documentation is still the same from 2.6 to 3, so Im not sure what happend!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem adding **cordova.js** file to platforms/ios/www/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This solution solved the same problem in my project, Your comment does not provide an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You should add File plugin to your app using:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

You may want to check this:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Answer (score 0):

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem"); 
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);   
}
function fail() {
   console.log("failed to get filesystem");
}
```